# Zero diagonal nonsymmetric block checkerboard matrix: orbits and numerical ranges

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be a nonsymmetric zero diagonal matrix with a zero/non-zero pattern which is symmetric and [persymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix) (i.e. symmetric in the northeast-to-southwest diagonal).

If $A$ has any kind of block checkerboard pattern, or an offset of a block checkerboard pattern that conserves symmetry and persymmetry (of the pattern), then $A^k, k=2n+1, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ has zero diagonal.

1) Is there a necessary and sufficient condition on the zero/non-zero pattern to get a zero diagonal $A^k, k=2n+1, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$?

If $A^k, k=2n+1, n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is traceless, then the spectrum of $A$ is symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis.

2) Is the numerical range (i.e. [field of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range), $W(A)=\left\{ \frac{v^* A v}{v^* v}, v \in \mathbb{C}^m, v\ne 0 \right\}$) always symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis as well?

Examples:
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{0 &2 &0 &-4\\
         1 &0 &2 &0 \\
         0 &-1 &0 &8 \\
        -4 &0 &7 &0}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\pmatrix{0 &0 &3 &-4\\
0 &0 &-1 &3 \\
3 &-1 &0 &0 \\
-4 &3 &0 &0}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\pmatrix{0 &-9 &1 &0\\
-9 &0 &0 &-1 \\
-1 &0 &0 &1 \\
0 &5 &7 &0}
\end{align}

Comment: You are using $n$ to mean two different things.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fixed! Thx!